# How to integrate TortoiseSVN-1.6.16 in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I did installed "TortoiseSVN-1.6.16" for client and Visual SVN in server. Its working fine independently on folder. But i need to integrate the same within visual studio 2010 and Sql Server management studio for 2008R2.
I need all your suggestion and help on the same.
Thanks in advance,
   Raju

Answer (score 4):

I think you need an add-on called AnkhSVN:

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this beta version addin.
http://vstortoise.codeplex.com/releases/view/77168